# PHP Mysql query, No Error, Wont Insert Row

Tags: php, mysql

The form submits correctly and it sends me an email. No error is reported and the SQL it creates works fine, I tested it at phpMyAdmin. mysql_error() raises nothing, it just doesn't add a row. Can anyone see what's going on?

```
<?PHP 

$to = "me@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Lead"; 
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y"); 
$time = date ("h:i A");
$mysql = mysql_connect("db.perfora.net:3306","db","password");

if(!$mysql)
{
    die("Could Not Connect: ".mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("db",$mysql);



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { 
    $name = $_POST['firstname']." ".$_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = "(".$_POST['areacode'].") ".$_POST['firstthree']."-".$_POST['lastfour'];
    $area = $_POST['area'];
    $lookdate = $_POST['lmm']."/".$_POST['ldd']."/".$_POST['lyyyy'];
    $lookdatedb = date("{$_POST['lmm']}.{$_POST['ldd']}.{$_POST['lyyyy']}");
    $movedate = $_POST['mmm']."/".$_POST['mdd']."/".$_POST['myyyy'];
    $movedatedb = date("{$_POST['mmm']}.{$_POST['mdd']}.{$_POST['myyyy']}");
    $loft = $_POST['loft'] ? "loft" : "";
    $highrise = $_POST['highrise'] ? "highrise" : "";
    $traditional = $_POST['traditional'] ? "traditional" : "";
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Leads 
            (Name, Email, Phone, Area, LookDate, MoveDate, Loft, HighRise, Traditional, Price, Comments) 
            VALUES 
            ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$area', '$lookdatedb', '$movedatedb', '{$_POST['loft']}', '{$_POST['highrise']}', '{$_POST['traditional']}', '$price', '$comments')";

if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  echo "Row added.";
}
else
{
  echo "Error adding row: " . mysql_error();
  echo("\n\n".$sql);
}


$msg = "
    New Lead Submitted On $date at $time.\n\n

    Name: $name\n
    Email: $email\n
    Phone: $phone\n
    Area: $area\n
    Look Date: $lookdate\n
    Move Date: $movedate\n
    Type: $loft $highrise $traditional \n
    Price: $price\n
    Comments: $comments\n


";  

}
mysql_close($mysql);
mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From:$email"); 
if ($forward == 1) { 
    header ("Location:$location"); 
} 
else { 
    echo "Thank you for submitting our form. We will get back to you as soon as possible."; 
} 

?>
```

Response:

> Thank you for submitting our form. We will get back to you as soon as possible.

Generated SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Leads (Name, Email, Phone, Area, LookDate, MoveDate, Loft, HighRise, Traditional, Price, Comments) VALUES ('work work', 'work@work.com', '(214) 131-4131', 'dallas', '02.18.2010', '02.25.2010', '', '1', '1', '$333333333333333333', '33fdsdfsdfsd')
```

Database Structure:

[http://imgur.com/iQHRk.jpg](https://imgur.com/iQHRk.jpg)

Comment: You could at least state some question (just in order to be polite).

Comment: Man ... Using THAT many embedded variables in strings is really annoying, and probably bound to cause errors in the future.

Comment: Where is `$forward` defined at, besides the `if ($forward == 1)`? Am I blind?

Comment: @Anthony Forloney: No you are not, it is not defined , but it is not part of the problem.

Comment: @anthony The only way I could see forward being defined is if he is expecting a string like `example.com?forward=1&location=http://mywebaddress`. Looking at the rest of the code, I wouldn't doubt it either.

Comment: You, my friend, are asking for SQL injection.

Comment: I know its not relevant, it just bothers me that I need to know where it is. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, your DB connection handle is obviously referenced by **$mysql**, but you've done this:

```
if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
```

Your DB handler is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

should return something why don't you take a look at that

i.e.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

It's a best practice to check for errors when you can.

Also to be noted, you are not escaping any of the user input so your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). please use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: I did that, I have the wrong code up. mysql_error() raises no error, it just says: "Invalid query: ".

Comment: @unknown (google): So maybe your query is wrong? *it just says*, come on **this is** your problem. What does `print_r($sql)` give your? And please put this into your question.

Comment: output the sql with `echo` or `vardump` and try on phpmyadmin/mysql query tool.

Comment: I tried the sql using echo and it worked fine and inserted a row in phpMyAdmin, but from my form it does nothing and mysql_error() raises nothing.

Comment: please add to your question the DESC of your table + an example of the outputted SQL

Answer (score 0):

take the post variable in another variable and then pass to the insert query i think it will be work
like this

$sql = "INSERT INTO Leads 
            (Name, Email, Phone, Area, LookDate, MoveDate, Loft, HighRise, Traditional, Price, Comments) 
            VALUES 
            ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$area', '$lookdatedb', '$movedatedb', '$loft', '$highrise', '$traditional', '$price', '$comments')";

mysql_query($sql);